# Pexpect if else statement

Tags: python, pexpect, asa

I am trying to create a script which clears ciscoasa bad xlate.

To check bad xlate I run sh xlate | in 500 and if it gets a reply then it should send a clear command.  If I don't do it, ciscoasa won't allow new vpn tunnels.

I need help with the if else statement.  Otherwise, the script is working fine.  Here is my code:

```
import pexpect
import re

password1="abc"
password2="abc"
router="127.0.0.20"
user="user"


#Extracting IP out of xlate command
class sendip(object):
    def ip(self,reply):
    divide=reply[15:32]
    extract_ip = re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', divide )
    for ip in extract_ip:
      send = 'clear local-host '+ip
      return send
clearVPN = sendip()

#ssh into ciscoasa userop5@ip
child = pexpect.spawn ('ssh ' + user + '@' + router)
child.expect ('.*assword:.*')
child.sendline (password1)

#enable mode
child.expect ('.*>.*')
child.sendline ('ena')
child.expect ('.*assword:.*')
child.sendline (password2)

# after enabling send test command
child.sendline ('terminal pager 0')
child.sendline ('show run | include http')
child.expect ('enroll*')
print child.before

# Here it sends command
child.sendline('sh xlate | i 500')
child.expect ('ciscoasa#.*')
print child.after

if child==1:  # If receive reply then extract IP and send clear memory
    child.expect('UDP.*')
    message = child.before
    child.sendline(clearVPN.ip(message)) #extract ip from there reply and send clear
    print child.before
    child.expect('clearing.*')
    print child.before
else:         # Otherwise memory is not full
    child.expect ('ciscoasa#.*')
    print 'Memory is empty'
    print child.after

child.sendline('exit')
child.close() # close ssh
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that what you need is use multiple patterns in the call to `child.expect` before the `if` statement. This way you'll be able to make a decision based on the response output to the last command send to the terminal.

For more information please have look at the [lists if patterns](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect#Lists_if_patterns) section in the documentation.